# The type initializer for 'Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver.operations_research_constraint_solverPINVOKE' threw an exception

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-api, or-tools

I have a google routing web service. it works in a local run project.
but when I upload it on the host I get this error message:

> The type initializer for
> 'Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver.operations_research_constraint_solverPINVOKE'
> threw an exception.

**notes**

1-I use vs 2019
2- I set enable-32-bit-application to false in my Plesk host panel
3- I build my project in 64 bit
4- I installed `google.ortool` by the package manager download

my code is :

```cs
static List<int> PrintSolution(in RoutingModel routing, in RoutingIndexManager manager, in Assignment solution, ref bool HasErr, ref string ErrMsg)
{
    List<int> orderIndex = new List<int>();
    try
    {     
        long routeDistance = 0;
        var index = routing.Start(0);
        while (routing.IsEnd(index) == false)
        {           
            orderIndex.Add((int)index);
            var previousIndex = index;
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index));
            routeDistance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(previousIndex, index, 0);
        }     
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        HasErr = true;
        ErrMsg = "GetIndexOrderLocations " + e.Message;
        orderIndex = null;
    }

    return orderIndex;
}

public static List<int> GetIndexOrderLocations(/String[] args/long[,] DistanceMatrix, ref bool HasErr, ref string ErrMsg)
{
    RoutingModel routing = null;
    RoutingIndexManager manager = null;
    Assignment solution = null;
    List<int> Result = new List<int>();
    try
    {
        // Instantiate the data problem.
        DataModel data = new DataModel();

        // Create Routing Index Manager
        manager = new RoutingIndexManager(/ data./ DistanceMatrix.GetLength(0), data.VehicleNumber, data.Depot);

        // Create Routing Model.
        routing = new RoutingModel(manager);

        int transitCallbackIndex = routing.RegisterTransitCallback((long fromIndex, long toIndex) => {
            // Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
            var fromNode = manager.IndexToNode(fromIndex);
            var toNode = manager.IndexToNode(toIndex);
            return/* data.*/DistanceMatrix[fromNode, toNode];
        });

        // Define cost of each arc.
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transitCallbackIndex);

        // Setting first solution heuristic.
        RoutingSearchParameters searchParameters =
            operations_research_constraint_solver.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters();
        searchParameters.FirstSolutionStrategy = FirstSolutionStrategy.Types.Value.PathCheapestArc;

        // Solve the problem.
        solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(searchParameters);

        if (routing == null || manager == null || solution == null)
            return null;

        Result = PrintSolution(routing, manager, solution, ref HasErr, ref ErrMsg);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        HasErr = true;
        ErrMsg = "GetIndexOrderLocations " + e.Message;
    }

    // Print solution on console.
    return Result;
}
```

Why I get this error?

Comment: try after installing Visual C++ Redistributables on machine

Comment: @viveknuna nuna On my host? or on my windows that i coding on it?

Comment: on host. and check the framework also

Comment: @viveknuna my host has Plesk control panel. how i do it?

Comment: refer this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

Comment: @viveknuna this link gives me a link to download the setup file. but how to install it on plesk control panel

Comment: Sorry I have no idea of plesk. Just study this document and see if something wrong https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/administrator-guide/web-hosting/configuring-aspnet-windows.60322/

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue locally on my PC; it works, but when I deploy it to production on another server, it fails and generates the same error. I found that the problem stems from missing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable libraries; you can download the x86 and x64 installers from here

Url: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-and-2022

[Image of the x86 and x64 installers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXdOZ.png)